# Basis of matrix using powers less than rank of generalized eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a $k × k$ matrix $K$ with just one real eigenvalue $λ$, of algebraic multiplicity $k$. Assume that there exists a generalized eigenvector $v$ of rank $k$. Prove that $B = {(K − λI)^{k−1}v, (K −λI)^{k−2}v, . . . , v}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^k.$

I know that $A(K − λI)^{k-1}v = λv$
And $(K − λI)^k =0$. And for the set to be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$, they must be linearly independent and span $\mathbb{R}^k$. I'm just not really sure how to prove that. Usually, I'd want to set up a Matrix with those vectors as the column vectors and show that rank = k, or equivalently that kernel = $0$. But I'm not sure how to go about either. It may be helpful to separate A into Jordan form using $A = PJP^{-1}$, although we've never really gone over that in my class. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $k$ vectors in a $k$-dimensional space, so need only prove linear independence to show it is a basis.

So let $A = (K -\lambda I)$. Then as $v$ is a generalized eigenvector of rank $k$, we have $v,Av,A^2v,\dots, A^{k-1}v$ all non-zero. Checking linear independence, suppose $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} c_iA^{i}v = 0$ for some $c_i$ for $i = 0,1,\dots, k$. Hitting this vector with $A^{k-1}$ and noting that $A^kw =0$ for all $w \in V$, we get $c_0A^{k-1}v = 0$. As $A^{k-1}v \neq 0$, then $c_0 = 0$.

Now we repeatedly apply powers of $A$ to isolate the next $c_i$. Below's the induction step.

Suppose $c_i = 0$ for $i<j$. Then applying $A^{k-j-1}$ to the vector, we get $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}c_iA^{k-j-1+i}v = \sum_{i=0}^{j}c_iA^{k-j-1+i}v = c_jA^{k-1}v = 0$. So $c_j = 0$.

Hence all $c_i = 0$ and so the $v,Av,A^2v,\dots,A^{k-1}v$ are linearly independent and form a basis.

Comment: Thanks! That was a nice way of thinking about it.